# Как не ждать ответа в asyncio python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, python-3.7

Необходимо запустить функцию bomder

```
async def bomber(text, id):
    global proxies
    try:
        mess = str(text).split(' ')
        itr = int(mess[1])
        numer = str(text)
        reg = numer[1:4]
        num = numer[4:11]
        number = reg+num
        proxyes = requests.post("https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=" + key + "&speed=1&type=socks5&limit=0")
        prox = proxyes.text.split("\r\n")
        for i in range(0, itr):
            proxy = random.choice(prox)
            proxies = {"https": "socks5h://" + proxy}
            task2 = asyncio.create_task(atb(reg, num))



    except:
        await bot.send_message(id, """123"""")
```

из функции проверки сообщения

```
async def check_mess(msg: types.Message):
    if "7" in msg.text:
        task = asyncio.create_task(bomber(msg.text, msg.from_user.id))
    else:
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, """123""")
```

P.s В данном виде не работает(

Answer (score 0):

вы пробовали такой вариант:

```
async def check_mess(msg: types.Message):
    if "7" in msg.text:
        task = asyncio.create_task(bomber(msg.text, msg.from_user.id))
        await task   #  <<<<<<< добавить эту строку
    else:
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, """123""")
```

Строго говоря, лично мне несколько непонятно где и как вы получаете event_loop. Приведите более полный пример кода

Comment: asyncio.create_task() эквивалентно asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task()

Comment: task не обязательно авэйтить, но выполнется он после того как закроется check_mess